# Unknow database [...] when selecting the database (Ubuntu)

Tags: database, ubuntu, mysql

I'm trying to work with MySQL on my laptop (Ubuntu)  and always that I have to export a .sql file to database, the console show me the same message: "unknow database Spotify (for example) when selecting the database".

The sql script is correct, and must work, but always show the same message; any solution?

```
CREATE DATABASE Spotify; 
USE Spotify ; 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Spotify.Usuarios ; 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Spotify.Usuarios 
( 
  iduser INT NULL , 
  user VARCHAR(10) NULL , 
  password VARCHAR(45) NULL , 
  reg VARCHAR(45) NULL 
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: You show neither your script nor the way you execute it. Hard to help you without any information.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved it: there was a problem with Ubuntu packages, and the mysql's installation didn't finished correctly